# In SwiftUI, what's causing "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints" trace?

Tags: swiftui, layout, constraints, warnings

The following app shows the above trace in the Xcode's output console:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TestApp: App {
    @State var isPresented = true

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationStack {
                VStack {
                }
                .navigationDestination(isPresented: $isPresented) {
                    Text("Cat")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Xcode: `Version 15.0.1`

The trace occurs because of the call `navigationDestination()` for `Text("Cat")`. Simply calling `Text("Cat")` without creating a new frame on the NavigationStack does not show the trace.

I don't see any discussion/documentation about layout with `navigationDestination()`.

How do I debug SwiftUI's **layout** issue in xcode in general?

Below is the full output from the xcode's console

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002126120 UILayoutGuide:0x600003b048c0'TitleViewGuide(0x103b0d6b0)'.trailing <= UILayoutGuide:0x600003b04c40'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.trailing   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002126530 UILayoutGuide:0x600003b048c0'TitleViewGuide(0x103b0d6b0)'.leading >= UILayoutGuide:0x600003b04c40'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.leading   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000021332f0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' _UINavigationBarContentView:0x103b0b360.width == 0   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000021268a0 'UIView-leftMargin-guide-constraint' H:|-(8)-[UILayoutGuide:0x600003b04c40'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'](LTR)   (active, names: '|':_UINavigationBarContentView:0x103b0b360 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000021252c0 'UIView-rightMargin-guide-constraint' H:[UILayoutGuide:0x600003b04c40'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide']-(8)-|(LTR)   (active, names: '|':_UINavigationBarContentView:0x103b0b360 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002126120 UILayoutGuide:0x600003b048c0'TitleViewGuide(0x103b0d6b0)'.trailing <= UILayoutGuide:0x600003b04c40'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.trailing   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Comment: Note, using Xcode 15.2, does not show any errors or warnings in my tests.

Comment: I upgraded Xcode to 15.2, and the problem still exists.